# Get angle inside a range

Tags: trigonometry

I have a Cartesian plane and wanted to decide if an angle is horizontal or vertical. I want to set a tolerance angle (say 5 degrees) so that if an angle is off plus or minus in this range from $x$-axis or $y$-axis I will consider it as horizontal or vertical angle. Any easy way to approach the problem will be welcomed?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What prevents you from checking if the angle $\theta$ is five degrees away from either of the axes?

Comment: In that case I have to make 4 separate comparisons which I think would be a brute force

Comment: Those four comparisons would take almost no time for a computer to make. Don't try to optimize your programs in places where it yields only small improvements - it will make your code harder to read/less intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of generality, I'm using radians instead of degrees, and am using a more general angle $\alpha$ instead of just $\pi/2$.

Given an angle $\theta$ and a small tolerance $\epsilon$, you are really interested in determining whether $\theta$ is within $\epsilon$ of any multiple of the positive number $\alpha=\tfrac\pi2$ (we assume $\epsilon$ is small relative to $\alpha$, so that it isn't the case that every angle is within tolerance).

Form the "remainder" $$r=\theta - \underbrace{\lfloor \theta/\alpha\rfloor}_{\textrm{integer}}\cdot\alpha$$ (here "$\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$" is the greatest integer function) so that necessarily you have $0\leq r<\alpha$ (this is just the fractional portion of the angle remaining after peeling away as many integral multiples of $\alpha$ as possible). Now $$r\in[0,\alpha)=\underbrace{[\epsilon,\alpha-\epsilon]}_{\textrm{out of tolerance}}\cup(\underbrace{[0,\epsilon)\cup(\alpha-\epsilon,\alpha)}_{\textrm{within tolerance (2 cases)}})$$ so we decide as follows.

If $r\in[\epsilon,\alpha-\epsilon]$, then your angle $\theta$ is not within tolerance of any multiple of $\alpha$.

Otherwise, it is within tolerance, and you can "snap" your angle to that closest multiple of $\alpha$. There are two possibilities:

(1) if $r<\epsilon$, then snap to $\lfloor \theta/\alpha\rfloor\alpha$;

(2) if $r>\alpha-\epsilon$, then snap to $(\lfloor \theta/\alpha\rfloor+1)\alpha$.

I hope this helps.

**Addendum:** Here's a simple example, and it uses degrees instead of radians, to address questions in the comments. Let the angle be $-453^\circ$, and let the tolerance be $5^\circ$. The remainder is $$r=-453 - \lfloor -453/90\rfloor90=-453-(-6)90 = 87$$ (remember, $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ rounds *down*, so $\lfloor -5.0\bar{3}\rfloor = -6$). The remainder is in the interval $[0,90)$. We partition the interval as $[0,90)=[5,85]\cup([0,5)\cup(85,90))$.

The "out-of-tolerance" interval is $[5,85]$. Our remainder is *not* in this interval, so it is indeed within tolerance of some multiple of $90^\circ$. Now we check to see which one to choose. Since the remainder is in the *upper* tolerance zone $(85,90)$, we snap to $((-6)+1)90^\circ=-450^\circ$.

If the remainder had been in the *lower* tolerance zone $[0,5)$, we would have snapped to $(-6)90^\circ=-540^\circ$, but that was not the case.

Comment: What does _t_ denotes in the remainder formula?

Comment: Oops, that should be $\theta$, not $t$. Will correct that. Note this is just a fancy way of saying that $r$ is the remainder after dividing by $\alpha$. Your angle can be written uniquely as $\theta = \textrm{integer}\times\alpha + \textrm{remainder}$ where $0\leq\textrm{remainder}<\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks MPW! But I wonder how it functions for negative angles..

Comment: It works exactly correctly. In that case, the integer $\lfloor\theta\alpha\rfloor$ is negative.

Comment: There, I've added an example to the end. It uses a negative angle, and uses degrees instead of radians. Hope that explains it all.